# C#: Unregistering an event does not work in a WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I had a working user control in winForms and decided on porting it to WPF.
the control is a preview control for kinect sensor and supports all 3 streams (Color, depth, skeleton). When I'm changing the ViewMode (a property of my control) it should unregister the handler from the event.

Take a look at the code:

```
switch (viewMode)
{
    case KinectViewMode.Color:
        Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= new EventHandler<ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(kinect_ColorFrameReady);
        if (!DoesEventHeveListeners("_colorFrameReadyContextHandler"))
            Kinect.ColorStream.Disable();
        break;
    case KinectViewMode.Depth:
        Kinect.DepthFrameReady -= kinect_DepthFrameReady;
        if (!DoesEventHeveListeners("_depthFrameReadyContextHandler"))
            Kinect.DepthStream.Disable();
        break;
    case KinectViewMode.Skeleton:
        Kinect.SkeletonFrameReady -= kinect_SkeletonFrameReady;
        if (!DoesEventHeveListeners("_skeletonFrameReadyContextHandler"))
        {
            Kinect.SkeletonStream.Disable();
        }
        break;
    case KinectViewMode.None:
        Kinect.SkeletonFrameReady -= kinect_SkeletonFrameReady;
        if (!DoesEventHeveListeners("_skeletonFrameReadyContextHandler"))
        {
            Kinect.SkeletonStream.Disable();
        }
        Kinect.DepthFrameReady -= kinect_DepthFrameReady;
        if (!DoesEventHeveListeners("_depthFrameReadyContextHandler"))
            Kinect.DepthStream.Disable();
        Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= kinect_ColorFrameReady;
        if (!DoesEventHeveListeners("_colorFrameReadyContextHandler"))
            Kinect.ColorStream.Disable();
        registeredToEvent = false;
        break;
    }
}

viewMode = value;

switch (viewMode)
{
    case KinectViewMode.Color:
        Kinect.ColorFrameReady += new EventHandler<ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(kinect_ColorFrameReady);
        if (!Kinect.ColorStream.IsEnabled)
            Kinect.ColorStream.Enable();
        break;
    case KinectViewMode.Depth:
        Kinect.DepthFrameReady += new EventHandler<DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(kinect_DepthFrameReady);
        if (!Kinect.DepthStream.IsEnabled)
        {
            depthPixels = new short[Kinect.DepthStream.FramePixelDataLength];
            colorPixels = new byte[sizeof(int) * Kinect.DepthStream.FramePixelDataLength];
            Kinect.DepthStream.Enable();
        }
        break;
    case KinectViewMode.Skeleton:
        Kinect.SkeletonFrameReady += new EventHandler<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(kinect_SkeletonFrameReady);
        if (!Kinect.SkeletonStream.IsEnabled)
            Kinect.SkeletonStream.Enable();
        break;
    case KinectViewMode.None:
        break;
}

if (ViewMode != KinectViewMode.None)
    registeredToEvent = true;
```

Why does this code work in winForms and not in WPF?

Comment: Could you limit the code snippet above to contain the smallest possible example only?

Comment: In addition to Uwe's question, are you getting any compile-time/runtime error(s)?

Comment: No, no runtime/compiler errors.
I put a breakpoint on the line:
    Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= new EventHandler<ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(kinect_ColorFrameReady);

to make sure the runtime does reach it and still the event triggers.

Comment: For testing purpose, can you try `Kinect.ColorFrameReady = (EventHandler<ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs>) Delegate.Remove(Kinect.ColorFrameReady, EventHandler<ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(kinect_ColorFrameReady));` and keep doing it unless `Delegate.Remove(..)` return null?

Comment: Thanks Vulcan,
But I cannot use Delegate.Remove with the Kinect.ColorFrameReady as the first argument. this is the compiler error: "The event 'Microsoft.Kinect.KinectSensor.ColorFrameReady' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="

Comment: I've also tried using the EventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(object target, Delegate handler) without any success.

Comment: Looks like a CLR bug for my opinion.